# Nextcloud page error in MIME type ('text/html') with Nginx

Tags: nginx, mime-types, nextcloud

Here is the error code:

I see the code of main.js is a file type of HTML, but somehow we get a file type of .js.

The same situation in .css file, so I get a non-complete NextCloud web page.
How should I do to make it match the right file type? and get a complete NextCloud webpage.

[image]